# Angular2 load flat json into nested reactive form (structures are not the same)

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a service that returns a (flat) json like this:

```
{
  Name: "name",
  email: "name@email.com",
  address: "some address",
  city: "some city"
}
```

And I need to load that json into the following (nested) reactive form:

```js
    this.resourceForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      formArray: this.formBuilder.array([
        this.formBuilder.group({
          name: [null, Validators.required],
          email: [null, Validators.required],
        }),
        this.formBuilder.group({
          address: [null, Validators.required],
          city: [null, Validators.required],
        }),
      ])
    });
```

I tryed with the following code, but it fails because the form doesn't have the same structure than json data:

```js
      protected loadResource() {
        if (this.currentAction === 'edit') {
          this.route.paramMap.pipe(
            switchMap(params => this.resourceService.getById(+params.get('id')))
          ).subscribe(
              (resource) => {
                this.resource = resource;
                this.resourceForm.patchValue(resource); 
              });
        }
      }
```

How can I (automatically?) get this flat json data loaded into that nested reactive form?  Is there a generic way to do that?

Comment: Why are you using a form array wrapper? PatchForm won’t work with a form array. Simplify you formGroup to match the API model..

Answer (score 0):

There is something odd in your formGroup structuring. The way I use FormArray is always as an array of the same type of FormGroups, I am assuming you had your own reasons to do it that way. 
The way you should set the data in the form is as follows:

```
....
).subscribe(
  (resource) => {
    const {Name, email, address, city} = resource;
    const formArray = this.resourceForm.get('formArray');
    formArray.at(0).setValue({name: Name, email});
    formArray.at(1).setValue({address, city});
  }
);
...
```

That should fix your example. First we destructure the resource object into its different attributes and then we set them in the form (I had to do it the long way with Name because one starts with uppercase and the other one is lowercase).

Comment: David G, that structure is because I am using the Angular Material stepper (linear) and I need to match the groups field to the respective step. The capital N was a mistype but I got the point. Thanks.